# Rails: Grouping Model records, then manipulating values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am grouping Model instances, by attribute, then manipulating the hash values.

```
Product.create(id: 1, name: "alpha", value: "apple")
Product.create(id: 2, name: "beta", value: "bongo")
...
```

We want the form: `[["alpha"],[["apple"],[1]]],[[beta],[["bongo"],[2]]]...]`

```
array = []
array1 = []
Product.all.group_by(&:name).each do |a|
  a[1].each do |b|
    array1 << [b.value,b.id]
  end
  array << [a[0],array1]
  array1 = []
end
```

Where `a` and `b` are iterator variables, `array1`  contains the ith a[1] values, and `array` contains the desired output structure.

This works, but is ugly. Can you accomplish this more cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = Product.all.group_by(&:name).map { |name, products|
  [name, products.map { |product| [product.value, product.id] }]
}
```

I believe this is what you want, but not 100% sure. Please try to use descriptive names, it takes a lot of effort to figure what `array1`, `b` and similar non-identifying identifiers are. It is also nice if you post an example of the output structure.

Comment: Great Job, you did it! That looks nice, thank you. I'll practice clarity with an edit.